# Loading truthtable into 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to copy a truth table into a 2D vector. The first number is the number of input for the table, so I take in the first line, then I start populating the vector. Here is a truth table from sample.txt:

```
4
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string getFileName();
string userFile;
fstream file;
int width;
vector < vector <int> >newArray; // 2d array as a vector of vectors

int main() {
    vector < vector <int> >array; // 2d array as a vector of vectors
    int row = 0; // Row counter
    int col = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int add = 0;
    userFile = getFileName();
    // Read file
    file.open(userFile.c_str(), ios::in); // Open file

    if (file.is_open()) { // If file has correctly opened...

        // Output debug message
        cout << "File correctly opened" << endl;
        string nLine;
        string line;
        getline(file, nLine);
        width = atoi(nLine.c_str());
        cout << "Width: " << width << endl;


        // Dynamically store data into array
        while (getline(file, nLine)) { // ... and while there are no errors,
            vector <int> rowVector(width-1); // vector to add into 'array' (represents a row)
            array.push_back(rowVector); // add a new row,

            cout << "row" << row <<": ";
            col = 0;
            for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < nLine.size(); ++i) { //iterate string
                if(nLine[i] == '1'){
                    array[row][col] = 1;
                    cout << " Col " << col << ": " << array[row][col];
                    col++;
                }
                else if(nLine[i] == '0'){
                    array[row][col] = 0;
                    cout << " Col " << col << ": " << array[row][col];
                    col++;
                }
                else{ //skip spaces

                }           
            }
            cout << endl;
            row++; // Keep track of actual row 
        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    file.close();

    cout << "Copied" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= width; j++){
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //erase lines that have output of 0
    // for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    //  if(array[i][width] == 0){
    //      cout << i << " " << array[i][width]<< endl;
    //      array.erase(array.begin() + i);
    //      count++;
    //  }
    // }
    row -= count;
    cout << "New rows: " << row << endl;





    return 0;
}

string getFileName(){
    cout << "Enter file name pls: " << endl;
    cin >> userFile;

    file.open(userFile.c_str(), ios::in); // Open file
    if (file.is_open()) { // If file has correctly opened...
        cout << "File correctly opened" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        getFileName();
    }
    file.close();
    return userFile;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the execution:

[image: output Screenshot]

The rows and columns all seem to be correct when I output them as I place them into the vector, but then when I go back, the first 8 lines or so are completely wrong and the rest are correct...I am not sure why. I print it right after I close the file(line 67), after the if(file.is_open()) statement.

Thanks for the help in advance,
All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
vector <int> rowVector(width-1); // vector to add into 'array' (represents a row)
```

you declare size of `rowVector` is `width-1`, in this test case your `width` is `4`, so size of `rowVector` is 3.  But your test case has 5 column with `0` or `1`. So you trying to access out of bounds index which shows undefined behavior.

To solve this make `rowVector` size equals to `width+1`

```
vector <int> rowVector(width+1); // vector to add into 'array' (represents a row)
```